# CFQuery Getting GeneratedKey from Multiple Insert into SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, coldfusion, railo, lucee

I am trying to get generated keys (or identitycol) of rows I am inserting using the multiple insert syntax.

```
<cfquery>
        CREATE TABLE TempPerson
            (
            PersonID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
            LastName varchar(20),
            FirstName varchar(20)
            );
</cfquery>

<cfquery result="qrResult">
    INSERT INTO TempPerson( lastName, firstName )
    VALUES( 'Smith', 'Michael' ), ('Jones','Ricky')
</cfquery>

<cfdump var="#qrResult#">
```

I ran this in both CF10 and Railo 4.2 in combination with both SQL Server and MySQL.

**CF10 with SQL Server** - no GeneratedKey returned.  Only recordCount variable

```
RecordCount = 2
```

**CF10 with MySQL** - get the identity columns as a list, but the wrong recordCount

```
GeneratedKey = 1,2
RecordCount = 1
```

**Railo 4.2 with SQL Server** - gets only the last identity column

```
GeneratedKey = 2
RecordCount = 2
```

**Railo 4.2 with MySQL**  - get identity columns as a list, and the right recordCount

```
GeneratedKey = 1,2
RecordCount = 2
```

So it looks like there is no consistency in the 4 permutations.   But my most urgent issue is whether there is a way to get the generated keys from SQL Server running with CF10.  Is there?

Comment: Given some of the quirks in earlier versions, I started using SQL Server's `OUTPUT` option instead of cfquery result. [Old blog entry](http://cfsearching.blogspot.com/2009/04/ms-sql-2005-more-on-underused-output.html) (no longer maintained). It is a little more work, but I have found the results more consistent than cfquery result over the various versions.  If you do not find a working fix for CF10, give it a whirl and see if it works.

Comment: That probably works for SQL Server, but I was hoping to be able to use the same sql syntax and code between the two sql flavors.  Maybe wishful thinking?

Comment: *Maybe wishful thinking* Unfortunately, yes. Their syntax/handling is different.

Answer (score 2):

Using the sql output

```
<cfquery name="qrResult">
  INSERT INTO TempPerson( lastName, firstName )
  OUTPUT Inserted.PersonID
  VALUES( 'Smith', 'Michael' ), ('Jones','Ricky') 
</cfquery>
```

It can then be used as regular data

Comment: One small correction. OUTPUT will return the data like a regular resultset. To capture it, you need to the cfquery "name" attribute, rather than "result".  Side note, too bad there is not a generic equivalent that would work with MySQL as well.  Closest you can get is a trigger...